# parse.com cloud code set version?

Tags: parse-platform, version

I am new to parse and I am trying to figure out how to handle the version number.

I have been deploying some cloud code a bunch of times. So when I last deployed it gave me this message:

```
Uploading source files
Finished uploading files
New release is named v18 (using Parse JavaScript SDK v1.2.19)
```

So I thought I could go and hit:
https://api.parse.com/**18**/functions/someFunctionIWrote

So there I tried to use version 18 because of what I saw after deploying. **That does not work** and it returns a 404.

So, then I tried to hit:
https://api.parse.com/**1**/functions/someFunctionIWrote

this works and return the JSON I wanted.

So, what am I missing here?

I thought that every time I deploy the version would match. Do I need to specifically go in and change the current version somehow?

Can somebody help understand how to think about this correctly?

Thank you

Comment: The number in the URL has nothing to do with the number of the release you get when deploying your cloud code. If I recall correctly this is the version of the Parse API, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran a "parse deploy" it put v18 up there for you the URL stays the same.

The version in cloud can be verified in the terminal by typing: "parse releases"